# Fake terminal browser - how to make it respond

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a terminal in my browser, which I did, but I don't know how to make it so that if I type a "command", it responds with something in the "terminal". Here's my code:

```
<body>
<div id="screen">$&gt;<input></input></div>
<script>
$("#screen input").focus();
$("#screen input").on('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.which === 13) {// Enter key pressed
        var $this = $(this),
            val = $this.val();
        $this.focus().val('');
        if(val === "hello world") {
            //respond with something in the terminal here
        }
    }
});
</script>
</body>
```

So I just want it to respond with something in the terminal when I do the command "hello world".

Comment: The same way you are erasing the value... `$this.val('Hi.');`.

Comment: I want it so that it's not in the input, it's outside of it so it can't be edited @Santi

Comment: Scott posted a good solution while I was responding, check out his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add a fake "console" output area. So, something like this?

FYI: `$this.focus().val('');` should just be: `$this.val('');` and `<input>` elements don't have a closing tag (`</input>`)

```js
// Get reference to the output area
var $out = $("#output");

$("#screen input").focus();
$("#screen input").on('keyup', function(event) {

    if(event.which === 13) {
      // Enter key pressed
      var $this = $(this);
      var val = $this.val();
      
      if(val === "hello world") {
        $out.append(">> Hello Galaxy<br>");
      }
      
      $this.val('');
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family:"courier new", monospaced;
  border-radius:5px;
  border:2px solid black;
  height:60vh;
  background-color:rgba(200,200,200, .5);
  padding:10px;
}

input { 
  background-color:rgb(0, 150, 0);
  color: #ff0;
  font-weight:bold;
  letter-spacing:.2em;
}
#output { 
  color:#000; 
  background-color:rgba(200,200,200, .25);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="screen">$&gt;<input></div>

<!-- This is the output area -->
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for

Comment: @Gavwin Added some styling just for fun!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value of the input by passing a string to [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="screen">$&gt;<input></input></div>
<script>
$("#screen input").focus();
$("#screen input").on('keydown', function(event) {
    if(event.which === 13) {// Enter key pressed
        var $this = $(this),
            val = $this.val();
        $this.focus().val('');
        if(val === "hello world") {
            $this.val('hi!')  // just set the val
        }
    }
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I want it so that it's not in the input, it's outside of it so it can't be edited.

Comment: Scott's solution will work then-- next time mention explicitly where you'd like the output to display in the question :)